# Custom text output for entity reference fields

Tags: entities, tokens, display-suite

In my content type I have an entity reference field. With this field editors can create internal links effordlessly with the autocomplete function.

What I want to achieve is that editors can now customize the text to output the referenced node. E.g. The editor creates a reference to a node and in a different field creates the "title" of the reference, she has just created. Thus references can have custom display titles.

I have tried the token formatters module (http://drupal.org/project/token_formatters) but to no avail.

In my particular case I have a field reference_text and have set the format of my entity reference field to "Tokenized text". In the "Text to output" field I have tried the following:
1) [node:reference_text]
2) [current-page:reference_text]

With 1) an empty field is displayed. With 2) I get an error message: Text output uses the following invalid tokes: [current-page:reference_text]

Not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different options here (there are probably more!):

1. Use the [linkit](http://drupal.org/project/linkit) module in combination with [wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and, say, the tinyMCE editor. This allows users to insert node reference links into wysiwyg text areas.
2. a.  Create a textfield for the link text in addition to the entity reference field.

   b.  In the template file for the content type (node--CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php), output the links manually, something like:

   $path = 'node/' . $node->YOUR_ENTITY_REF_FIELD['und'][0]['target_id'];

   ```
   $link_text = $node->YOUR_LINK_TEXT_FIELD['und'][0]['value'];

   print l($link_text, $path);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I wanted to stay away from creating a node template as I am not particularly good at PHP but will try a solution. I had hoped that I could do this with tokens, though. The linkit module is unfortunately tied to an editor, which I do not want my clients' to use. I will let you know about the template approach.

Comment: I solved it with the linkit module. I created a text field and chose the linkit option in the configuration of the field. Thanks.